# Why are the four launch opportunities within each Inspiration4 launch window "about an hour apart"?

Tags: launch, mission-design, launch-window, inspiration-4

In the SpaceX Inspiration4 Launch broadcast at about `T-01:31:05` (91 minutes before launch) the process for selection of launch windows for the mission is roughly outlined:

> So the procedure for picking the launch window is actually a little bit different.
>
> We reserved a couple of days -- a couple of *twenty four hour days* for the mission, but had to wait until L minus five, or five days before the first launch day that was selected to narrow it down to twelve hours. And then after that, we waited until L minus three to select the five hour window that we have today.
>
> **And then we have four opportunities in each of those launch windows about an hour apart**, to lift off.
>
> So it's a very unique case; so we really just knew just three days ago what the T zero in the launch window would be.

**Question:** Why are the four launch opportunities within each Inspiration4 launch window "about an hour apart"?

I don't know if it's relevant or not, but the orbital period of the final altitude of 575 km is about 96 minutes. I don't think it is relevant since there's no rendez-vous involved in this mission, but there could be an anti-rendez-vous; something at that altitude worth avoiding for example.

---

SpaceX Inspiration 4 Launch broadcast cued at about T-01:31:05 (91 minutes before launch) where the term "L minus five" is used:

Comment: A 5 hour window with 4 opportunities means they could actually be 96 minutes apart, matching the orbital period... just thinking...

Comment: It's possible they are talking about the recycle time. When they have a hold, they usually reset the clock to T-15 minutes, but I have never actually seen them pick the countdown back up. I would assume they need to defuel and refuel, and fueling starts at T-38 minutes. So, a couple of minutes for troubleshooting, 20 minutes for detanking, and then pick up the countdown at T-38 minutes would add up to "about an hour". This was a launch commentator making an unprepared remark, after all, not a PhD dissertation on orbital mechanics.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's [Jessie Anderson, a SpaceX Production and Engineering Manager](https://youtu.be/3pv01sSq44w?t=395) What is it about her running commentary throughout that makes you feel she is "unprepared"?